# How to avoid unauthorized access to Files inside CakePHP's webroot folder using ACL?

Tags: cakephp, components, acl, authentication

I have a folder inside my CakePHP webroot folder, I want [ONLY] logged-in users to access this folder/files inside webroot! Is it possible?

For example:

If not logged in:

www.example.com/app/webroot/pdf/word.doc

This should yield a message saying please login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible because the access to the files in the `webroot` folder is not handled by the framework.

The [media view](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) is probably what you are looking for.